# stock table for inventory database design architecture

Tags: sql, architecture

I am currently building a management system. Is it good practice to create a **balance table** for inventory to store the inventory at hand and constantly update the table if there are changes, or should one just directly query **total inventory ordered table - total inventory used table**? Which would be the most efficient and fastest way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a bad idea to use two separate tables. You will have to perform a join which is unnecessary. Simply have one table with an 'ordered' column and a 'used' column. In your query you can very efficiently calculate the net value e.g. :

```
SELECT ordered, used, (ordered - used) as net FROM inventory
```

Comment: yes, but I have to keep used and orders as separate tables as I have other column details for them. My question is whether I should use a balance table to store the net or just query it with a select using a join? What would be better practice?

Comment: Ok, That wasn't very clear from the question. Can you post the table structure of your tables.

Comment: However, assuming you have two tables with clustered primary keys (e.g. product_id), then a JOIN would be pretty efficient, so I wouldn't worry about it. On relational data my general rule is to keep things normalised and logically separated, and only store derived data when you can clearly see a bottleneck occurring in the future. Unless you are very careful, your stored derived data would likely get out of step with the source data. If you envisage these tables progressively getting *huge* over time then, I would consider using a row-update trigger to update a balance table.